# How to bulk load Items from a sharepoint list by multiple id's using pnpCore

Tags: c#, sharepoint, pnp-core-sdk

I'm working on trying to retrieve changed items in a sharepoint document list.

It's simple enough to "identify" the id's of the changed items.

```
IList documentsList = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Documents");
IList<IChange> changes = await documentsList.GetChangesAsync(new ChangeQueryOptions(false, false)
{
    Item = true,

    Add = true,
    Update = true,
    DeleteObject = true,
    Rename = true,
    Move = true,

    RecursiveAll = true,
});
```

however the next step is to iterate through the list and load each item one by one using their ItemId.

```
List<IChangeItem> changeItems = changes.Where(c => c is IChangeItem).Cast<IChangeItem>().ToList();

foreach (var change in changeItems)
{
    IListItem item = await documentsList.Items.GetByIdAsync(change.ItemId, p => p.Title, p => p.File, p => p.Folder, p => p.FileSystemObjectType);
}
```

Which results in a separate round trip to the sharepoint server and seems inefficient to me so I want to know how to bulk load or batch load based on a list of id's.

Neither the working with lists documentation
https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/listitems-intro.html
nor the Using Batching documentation
https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/basics-batching.html
seem to cover bulk retrieval of items by Id.

Batching examples seem to involve querying by a single property.

I'm looking for something that fits the functional intent of this...

```
var changeItemIds = changes.Where(c => c is IChangeItem).Cast<IChangeItem>().Select(c => c.ItemId).ToList();

var result = await documentsList.Items.GetByIdAsync
    .Where(i => changeItemIds.Contains(i.Id))
    .QueryProperties(p => p.Title, p => p.File, p => p.Folder, p => p.FileSystemObjectType)
    .ToListAsync();
```

however I appreciate that things are different in sharepoint and I expect that it won't look much like that at all.

Thanks in advance.